# Display data of one model into another in admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model shipment_track which is having one to one relation with order model.I can display shipment_track model in to admin but it shows only his the fields I want to show order price , status , address and other fields of order model to admin under shipment_track(Not editable).

so that admin have more information while he update the shipment model.

Is their any way so that i can do it in admin.py.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can provide more details to the question that you have asked.
As far as i have interpreted it.

You can do it in the following ways - -

If you are writing a basic modular code then you can send the details from order model to shipment model in a tuple.

This would have a security vulnerability, in that case you can use the oop model described in the answer above.

```
shipment
    track

track
    track

shipment.track

track.shipment

shipment.track.track_details

track.shipment.shipment_details
```

Comment: Actually i am using mezzanine + cartridge , They their default order model...but they do not have shipping track module so i am making this by myself so i need to display some order details in shipping model...

Comment: @user1746291 - Hey thats quite understandable, Using the catridge model explains the inclusion of the shopping cart. In case you need to customize it, I would suggest that you should take the second option given in my answer